# Unable to uninstall ruby gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have screwed up my rubygem dependencies.

This is my gem list

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.5, 1.3.6)
actionpack (2.3.5, 1.13.6)
actionwebservice (1.2.6)
activemodel (3.0.3)
activerecord (3.0.3, 2.3.5, 1.15.6)
activeresource (3.0.3, 2.3.5)
activesupport (3.0.3, 2.3.5, 1.4.4)
acts_as_ferret (0.4.3)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.7)
capistrano (2.5.2)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
daemons (1.0.10)
devise (1.0.5)
dnssd (0.6.0)
erubis (2.6.6)
fastthread (1.0.1)
fcgi (0.8.7)
ferret (0.11.6)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
highline (1.5.0)
hpricot (0.6.164)
i18n (0.4.2)
libxml-ruby (1.1.2)
mail (2.2.9)
mime-types (1.16)
mongrel (1.1.5)
needle (1.3.0)
net-scp (1.0.1)
net-sftp (2.0.1, 1.1.1)
net-ssh (2.0.4, 1.1.4)
net-ssh-gateway (1.0.0)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.1, 1.0.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.6)
rails (2.3.5, 1.2.6)
railties (3.0.3)
rake (0.8.7, 0.8.3)
RedCloth (4.1.1)
ruby-openid (2.1.2)
ruby-yadis (0.3.4)
rubygems-update (1.4.2)
rubynode (0.1.5)
sqlite3-ruby (1.2.4)
termios (0.9.4)
thor (0.14.4)
treetop (1.4.8)
tzinfo (0.3.23)
warden (1.0.3)
xmpp4r (0.4)
```

Now when I try to uninstall rails, I get this error

```
    dyres212-79:~ ranjiththavamaniraj$ sudo gem uninstall rails -v 2.3.5
Password:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d rails`
```

Comment: have yo tried just deleting all the files? As far as I know there are no system libraries or registry setting (windows),etc created when you install rails so just removing the files from your system is sufficient.  Next time use RVM.

Comment: Okie.. thanks for the reply.. im really stuck up with this.. what do i do next?? i want to remove all the gems.. pls help..

Comment: I'd just get rid of ruby entirely and reinstall. From what I can tell, you don't have anything important with your current installation

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests, that version of rails may not be present to be uninstalled. In any case I suggest you use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/). Its a much better practice, in order to manage multiple rubies and rails versions.